# OpenGL / Shader / Matrix : Weird scaling of the shape after a rotation of the view matrix

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, camera, shader

I try to display a triangle using OpenGL with Shader, and I have a problem when I move the camera. The orientation of my triangle seems ok, but the x and y scaling looks funny...

The two following images illustrate my problem : the left side of the image is the output I have using the shaders, and the right part is the representation of the same scene using JOGL functions (such as "glLookAt" / "glFrustum"). The two triangles should be the same, but it is not the case when I rotate the camera.

[image]

[image]

Here is the "main" of my vertex shader :

```
void main(void) {

varying_Color = attribute_Color;
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(attribute_Position,1.0);

}
```

Here is how I compute my projection matrix :

```
    final int height = getSurfaceHeight();
    final double aspect = getSurfaceWidth() / height;
    final double maxDim = getMaxEnvDim();
    final double zNear = maxDim / 1000;
    final double zFar = maxDim*10;
    final double frustum_length = zFar - zNear;
    double fW, fH;
    final double fovY = 45;
    if (aspect > 1.0) {
        fH = FastMath.tan(fovY / 360 * Math.PI) * zNear;
        fW = fH * aspect;
    } else {
        fW = FastMath.tan(fovY / 360 * Math.PI) * zNear;
        fH = fW / aspect;
    }

    projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    projectionMatrix.m00 = (float) (zNear / fW);
    projectionMatrix.m11 = (float) (zNear / fH);
    projectionMatrix.m22 = (float) -((zFar + zNear) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.m32 = (float) -((2 * zNear * zFar) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
```

Here is how I compute my view matrix :

```
public static double[] CrossProduct(final double[] vect1, final double[] vect2) {
    final double[] result = new double[3];
    result[0] = vect1[1] * vect2[2] - vect1[2] * vect2[1];
    result[1] = vect1[2] * vect2[0] - vect1[0] * vect2[2];
    result[2] = vect1[0] * vect2[1] - vect1[1] * vect2[0];
    return result;
}

public static double ScalarProduct(final double[] vect1, final double[] vect2) {
    return vect1[0]*vect2[0]+vect1[1]*vect2[1]+vect1[2]*vect2[2];
}

public static double[] Normalize(final double[] vect) {
    double[] result = new double[vect.length];
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.length ; i++) {
        sum += Math.abs(vect[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.length ; i++) {
        result[i] = vect[i] / sum;
    }
    return result;
}

public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(ICamera camera) {
    // see http://in2gpu.com/2015/05/17/view-matrix/
    Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();

    double[] fVect = new double[3]; // forward vector : direction vector of the camera.
    double[] sVect = new double[3]; // orthogonal vector : "right" or "sideways" vector.
    double[] vVect = new double[3]; // cross product between f and s.
    double[] pVect = new double[3]; // camera position.

    double sum = Math.abs(camera.getTarget().x - camera.getPosition().x)
            + Math.abs(camera.getTarget().y - camera.getPosition().y)
            + Math.abs(camera.getTarget().z - camera.getPosition().z);
    fVect[0] = -(camera.getTarget().x - camera.getPosition().x) / sum;
    fVect[1] = (camera.getTarget().y - camera.getPosition().y) / sum;
    fVect[2] = -(camera.getTarget().z - camera.getPosition().z) / sum;

    double[] crossProduct = CrossProduct(fVect,new double[]{camera.getOrientation().x,
            -camera.getOrientation().y,camera.getOrientation().z});
    sVect = Normalize(crossProduct);

    vVect = CrossProduct(sVect,fVect);

    pVect = new double[]{camera.getPosition().x,
            -camera.getPosition().y,camera.getPosition().z};

    viewMatrix.m00 = (float) sVect[0];
    viewMatrix.m01 = (float) sVect[1];
    viewMatrix.m02 = (float) sVect[2];
    viewMatrix.m03 = (float) -ScalarProduct(sVect,pVect);
    viewMatrix.m10 = (float) vVect[0];
    viewMatrix.m11 = (float) vVect[1];
    viewMatrix.m12 = (float) vVect[2];
    viewMatrix.m13 = (float) -ScalarProduct(vVect,pVect);
    viewMatrix.m20 = (float) fVect[0];
    viewMatrix.m21 = (float) fVect[1];
    viewMatrix.m22 = (float) fVect[2];
    viewMatrix.m23 = (float) -ScalarProduct(fVect,pVect);
    viewMatrix.m30 = (float) 0;
    viewMatrix.m31 = (float) 0;
    viewMatrix.m32 = (float) 0;
    viewMatrix.m33 = (float) 1;
    viewMatrix.transpose();
    return viewMatrix;
}
```

Notice that when I use a simple transformation matrix instead of the view matrix and if I apply a rotation to my triangle, it appears right. That leads me to the fact that the problem is from my view matrix, but I can't find my mistake...
Notice also that I have some weird "-y" to get the view matrix, because my openGL world is an indirect coordinate system.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Normalize` function is strange. You are not computing the Euclidean length of your vector but its uniform norm.

Try changing it to this:

```
double[] result = new double[vect.length];
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vect.length ; i++) {
    sum += Math.pow(vect[i], 2);
}
for (int i = 0; i < vect.length ; i++) {
    result[i] = vect[i] / Math.sqrt(sum);
}
return result;
```

You also have the exact same problem in your `createViewMatrix` function at this line:

```
double sum = Math.abs(camera.getTarget().x - camera.getPosition().x) +
Math.abs(camera.getTarget().y - camera.getPosition().y) + 
Math.abs(camera.getTarget().z - camera.getPosition().z);
```

Change it to:

```
double sum = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(camera.getTarget().x - camera.getPosition().x, 2) +
Math.pow(camera.getTarget().y - camera.getPosition().y, 2) + 
Math.pow(camera.getTarget().z - camera.getPosition().z, 2));
```

Comment: Wow ! Indeed, I had an error here, thanks ! But even with this modification, I still have the same problem I describe with the screenshots...

Comment: @Julien Mazars You do the exact same thing in `createViewMatrix`:   
`double sum = Math.abs(camera.getTarget().x - camera.getPosition().x)
            + Math.abs(camera.getTarget().y - camera.getPosition().y)
            + Math.abs(camera.getTarget().z - camera.getPosition().z);`

Comment: Oh yes you are right ! I'm so blind ^^. Thank you so much, it works perfectly now !